# How do I incorporate Vertex Buffer Array into my graphics program?

Tags: python, pyopengl, vertex-buffer

I am writing a 3d graphics toolkit for Python and PyQt5, using PyOpenGL. I am writing my own shaders to go with it, if that helps. What I am trying to do is go from using glBegin to using a Vertex Buffer Array. I have found the following on using VBOs:

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html - I could only scrape together a bit of information from this because it is in C/C++.

[How to get VBOs to work with Python and PyOpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179565/how-to-get-vbos-to-work-with-python-and-pyopengl) - This was in Python2 and was fairly limiting as a result.

I cannot, however, piece together what I need to take the vertexes of each of my shape objects and compile them into a scene VBO. I also have no idea how the data in an array is laid out. My initGL and paintGL functions are below, as are my vertex and fragment shaders' GLSL code.

```py
    def initGL(self):
        self.vertProg = open(self.vertPath, 'r')
        self.fragProg = open(self.fragPath, 'r')
        self.vertCode = self.vertProg.read()
        self.fragCode = self.fragProg.read()
        self.vertShader = shaders.compileShader(self.vertCode, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        self.fragShader = shaders.compileShader(self.fragCode, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        self.shader = shaders.compileProgram(self.vertShader, self.fragShader)

#paintGL uses shape objects, such as cube() or mesh(). Shape objects require the following:
#a list named 'vertices'  - This list is a list of points, from which edges and faces are drawn.
#a list named 'wires'     - This list is a list of tuples which refer to vertices, dictating where to draw wires.
#a list named 'facets'    - This list is a list of tuples which refer to vertices, ditating where to draw facets.
#a bool named 'render'    - This bool is used to dictate whether or not to draw the shape.
#a bool named 'drawWires' - This bool is used to dictate whether wires should be drawn.
#a bool named 'drawFaces' - This bool is used to dictate whether facets should be drawn.

    def paintGL(self):
        shaders.glUseProgram(self.shader)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(45, self.sizeX / self.sizeY, 0.1, 110.0)    #set perspective?
        glTranslatef(0, 0, self.zoomLevel)    #I used -10 instead of -2 in the PyGame version.
        glRotatef(self.rotateDegreeV + self.vOffset, 1, 0, 0)    #I used 2 instead of 1 in the PyGame version.
        glRotatef(self.rotateDegreeH, 0, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        for s in self.shapes:
            if s.drawWires:
                glBegin(GL_LINES)
                for w in s.wires:
                    for v in w:
                        glVertex3fv(s.vertices[v])
                glEnd()

            if s.drawFaces:
                glBegin(GL_QUADS)
                for f in s.facets:
                    for v in f:
                        glVertex3fv(s.vertices[v])
                glEnd()
```

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 120    
void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 120
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 0, 1, 0, 1 );
}
```

In the final form of this project, I want to have information in my buffer for vertex positions, color, and maybe even glow. (That will be achieved when I put this to ray marching eventually.) I also need a way to specify whether or not I should draw the wires and faces.

How do I set up and configure one or more VBOs to transfer all this information to the GPU and OpenGL?

Python 3.7.6, Windows 10

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hmm. I just swapped that out and it seems to work the same, so long as I make sure to import it from ```OpenGL.GL```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while longer researching, I decided to try using less specific search terms. I eventually stumbled upon this site: https://www.metamost.com/opengl-with-python/